# Box shadow doesn't extend all the way in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css

so I have a box-shadow that is on either side of my content at

www.heatherkirk.net. Haha, don't pay attention to my front page on IE (my portfolio listings are all messed up) if you choose to use it, that's a different problem entirely lol.

For Firefox and IE, it definitely extends all the way. However, on Chrome, it stops halfway and when I click on Inspect it shows that my main container stops halfway up the page (just on Chrome though). If anyone could answer for me, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I dont see a difference except that chrome's shadow is little leaner. The chrome inspect element shows that u have added -web-box-shadow. If you added it, then it is wrong, it should be -webkit, and thats for safari. for mozilla thats -moz. add like this and see if u find a difference.

```
#example1 {
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

Comment: Weird, because every time I look at mine to make changes on its css, it just stops halfway down the page. I've cleared cookies and everything, I've downloaded the latest version of Chrome. Hm. I did make the change (thank you for that), but it's still showing up oddly at least on my end.

Comment: @HeatherKirk I see in firefox that the shadow shows up until the half of 'Newest blog update" But on my chrome, it shows up until the end of "Newest blog update". I wish i could show you some screen shots but thats what i see here. I am still unable to understand your question.

Comment: Weird, you're right. It doesn't show up how I want on firefox or chrome. Okay, so I have my main container set as a height to 100%, and I would like for the box-shadow to extend until the bottom of my footer. However, it stops right around "Newest blog update". Is height set to 100% not good to do for a box-shadow?

Comment: I am trying to debug your site but am at work. My first suggestion is try id for main content. Next is validate your html from the page. open your site in firefox, right click to see source. copy the entire source and validate it here http://validator.w3.org/. Follow their advice when you have errors. Meanwhile I will try to see whats going on.

Comment: Ya this should work. Convert that main-content into an id and add the box shadow there. it will work.

Comment: Okay, I will continue to debug my site. However, I'm slightly confused by your answer. It sounds like you want me to turn the div class into an id, and post the html box shadow there. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, I got it! Thanks =)